# what is the life on unscoped objects injected by dagger2?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I understand that scoped objects injected via Dagger 2 lives as long as the class holding the object as well as the component are alive!

Now say for example I have fragment inside an activity, I want object let's say Object in the fragment, and the component lives inside the activity itself..

should that object be scoped or not?
my guess is it shouldn't, as when the fragment is destroyed, the object won't be garbage collected until the activity is destroyed, right?

so if the object is unscoped, will it be garbage collected once the fragment is destroyed, no matter whether the component is still alive or not?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

Dagger component doesn't hold reference to unscoped objects, they are always provided with @Provides method, it means they are independent from component. When you stop using them they die.

Whether to scope objects or not depends on your architecture, you might always want to create new Presenters, then scope is useless. Scope is useful only when you want to inject the same instance multiple times.